# applicationDidEnterBackground and network request

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I have an iOS game in which I track the number of levels a player plays in a session. A session corresponds to the period between the user pressing the app icon on the home screen and pressing the home button to leave the app.

Surprisingly I don't seem to be getting the leave event for a large fraction of my users. I have implemented the log transmission as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ...
    [[EventLogger sharedEventLogger] pushEvent:LEAVE_GAME];
}
```

...where EventLogger sends an **asynchronous** HTTP POST request using the ASIHTTP library.

Could it be that the system preempts the transmission before it finishes? It could be that the app crashes and never gets to this point, but that is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a) for this method?

" You should use this method to **release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough app state information to restore your app to its current state in case it is terminated later**. You should also disable updates to your app’s user interface and avoid using some types of shared system resources (such as the user’s contacts database)...**Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return**. If you need additional time to perform any final tasks, you can **request additional execution time from the system by calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler**:. In practice, you should return from applicationDidEnterBackground: as quickly as possible. **If the method does not return before time runs out your app is terminated and purged from memory**."

Sounds to me like what you're doing is not suggested for this method, but you can try using this beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler.

I can't be certain that this is the explanation for your issue, but it seems plausible and is consistent with the fact that it isn't being logged only for a portion of your users.

May also be of use:
The system sends a UIApplicationDidGoToBackground notification when the home button is pressed.